# Other than brute force, are there any attacks on Threefish-512 using only a single known plaintext block?

Tags: cryptanalysis, known-plaintext-attack

As per title, other than brute force, are there any attacks on Threefish-512 using only a single plaintext block? Are there any attacks like this in any other cipher?

Comment: A single plaintext/ciphertext pair is much too small a sample to do anything on modern ciphers. On older, or significantly broken ciphers, it may be enough for successful cryptanalysis though. For Threefish-512, there are none, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2010/02/new_attack_on_t.html),
there is an attack on 42 rounds of ThreeFish-512, but if you check out the [analysis](http://www.skein-hash.info/sites/default/files/axr.pdf), it relies on multiple plaintext values.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefish) lists no singular known plaintext attack, only a boomerang attack, which also depends on multiple known plaintexts.

So given these sources, it would seem there is not a well known and effective attack on three fish 512 with only one plaintext block.

Generally speaking, given only an encryption of a single plaintext block it would be difficult to use cryptanalysis to break a cipher. Even block cipher modes of operation which are deprecated, such as [ECB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29), will operate securely for single block-key encryptions.

The [Known-Plaintext-Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) seems to utilize single blocks of plaintext in some situations. That wiki site lists its usage on a cipher used during WWII, so technically **Yes**, there do exist ciphers which have been susceptible to a single known plaintext block at some points in history. But for modern ciphers, **No**, it does not seem to be an effective means of attack

Comment: Both attacks only work on reduced round ThreeFish, and not on the full Threefish. The first one only works that well on older versions of Threefish.

Comment: yep all of that it correct. I'll edit to make it more clear